# Android Firebase Order by name and by most popular title

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order my firebase query so that I can get data that shows most popular child Example I want to have a new post and other page shows most popular post. post that has most liked or viewed

Can someone help me

[image: how can i get popular videos that come from child with most views]

Comment: atleast show your database

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.